# How to use Twig template with SailsJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twig, sails.js

I am trying to set up SailsJS with Twig template engine & having bad luck.

This is what I followed:

- `Sails new my-project`
- `npm install consolidate`  [(Supported engines by Sails)](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js#supported-template-engines)
- `npm install twig`

Then in `config/views.js` I set `'extension': 'twig'`.

Now when I try to write any Twig code it doesn't render the result, it simply outputs the code in text form.

For example, I am trying to extend in homepage instead of rendering the header it is displaying plain text "`{% extends 'mylayout' %}`".

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I assume you followed the guide [here on the sails docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/view-engines) ? are you getting any other errors int he console?

Comment: Yes, I am following exactly this Doc & instructions. But, this is not working. There is no error as well. Swig:Twig code is not rendering anything its simply outputs it self as a text.

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of Sails and Twig?  This may be an issue with the Twig extension configuration - have you checked out the official [extending twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html) procedures ?